# Realm для WatchKit и iOS

Tags: swift3, realm

Привет! Помогите разобраться в вопросе связанным с Realm. Есть приложение для iOS и Watch Extension к нему. Мне удалось подключить к каждому из них Realm базу, но при добавлении информации в одну - например в iOS приложение она не отображается на часах. Как синхронизировать отображение?

Я использую такую функцию в обоих случаях:

```
func setDefaultRealmPath()
{
let directory: URL =  FileManager.default.containerURL(forSecurityApplicationGroupIdentifier: "group.com.gurman.watchTestApp")!

let fileRealmURL = directory.appendingPathComponent("db.realm")
realm = try! Realm(fileURL: fileRealmURL)

var config = Realm.Configuration.defaultConfiguration
config.fileURL = fileRealmURL

Realm.Configuration.defaultConfiguration = config

print("file url: \(realm.configuration.fileURL!)")
}
```

---

**UPDATE:**

Информация по транспортировке объекта класса с iPhone в Apple Watch:

Есть класс: "User"

```
class User: Object
{
    var name = String()
    var id = Int()
}
```

В iPhone, по нажатию по кнопке, выполняется следующая функция для отправки сообщения на часы:

```
func sendMessageToWatch()
{
    let newUser = User()
    newUser.name = "Marcus"
    newUser.id = 1

    let data = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: newUser)
    session.sendMessageData(data, replyHandler: nil, errorHandler: nil)
}
```

На часах выполняется следующая функция:

```
func session(_ session: WCSession, didReceiveMessageData messageData: Data, replyHandler: @escaping (Data) -> Void)
{
    NSKeyedUnarchiver.setClass(User.self, forClassName: "User")
    if (NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(with: messageData) as? User) != nil
    {
        newUser = User(value: messageData)
        labelUserName.setText(newUser.name)
        labelUserId.setText("\(newUser.id)")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

я думаю что проблема может быть в том, что у каждого девайса - айфон и часы - свой файл БД. Нельзя шарить файлы между WatchOS и iPhone таким способом. используйте WatchConnetivity

Comment: Дело в том, что я использую в данный момент WatchConnectivity. Приходится пробрасывать массивы через циклы из сообщений, а это как мне кажется не самый элегантный способ решения задачи ;)

Тогда вопрос такой: Возможно ли целиком пробрасывать классы, массивы или например Result<МойКласс>  через методы WatchConnectivity?

Comment: А может быть в самом Realm'е есть возможность синхронизации баз данных (merge?)?

Comment: ты должен реализовать протокол NSCoding в своем кастомном классе
Тогда можно будет переслать чистую Data Через WatchConnectivity
Card - мой кастомный класс. 

 let data = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: card ?? Card())
                                            WCSession.default().sendMessageData(data, ....

Comment: Можешь продублировать комментарий  в качестве ответа - иначе код комментария обрезается

Comment: да там не обрезается, это я просто кусочек вставил. Суть в том чтобы свой класс в Data представлять. А для этого сам класс должен реализовать протокол NSCoding

Comment: А как на принимающей стороне- на часах  код выглядеть будет? Там метод разархивации должен быть реализован?

Comment: Да, разархивация. вроде такого 

NSKeyedUnarchiver.setClass(Card.self, forClassName: "Card")
        if let card = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(with: data) as? Card {....

Comment: это в методе делегате 

public func session(_ session: WCSession, didReceiveMessageData messageData: Data, replyHandler: @escaping (Data) -> Swift.Void) {...

Comment: Попробовал, приложение падает с ошибкой
" 'Nsinvalidargumentexception', reason: '-[RLM: Unmanaged User encodeWithCoder:]: unrecognised selector sent to instance *место в памяти* " 
Обновил текст вопроса - посмотри после метки "UPDATE" правильно ли я тебя понял?

Comment: пересылка вроде верно, а сам класс User? NSCoding - реализовал?

Comment: Нет, подскажешь как реализовать его?

Comment: вообще посмотри что надо реализовать чтобы поддерживать этот протокол. Здесь же на стекОверфлоу, например. Там набор методов.

Comment: Понял, поищу, спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете использовать Realm в WatchOS и есть способы синхронизации.

Посмотреть пример можете [тут](https://academy.realm.io/posts/tutorial-sharing-data-between-watchkit-and-your-app/)